# How to pass parameters from gradle to ant?

Tags: gradle, ant

I have the following two files:

*build.gradle*:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

*build.xml*:

```
<project>
    <target name="hello">
        <echo>Hello, I'm ${testVar}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

How can I pass `testVar` variable from gradle to ant to trigger the ant build?

`gradle -PtestVar=John hello` outputs

```
> Task :hello
[ant:echo] Hello, I'm ${testVar}
```

This means that `testVar` isn't assigned a value.

I can pass `testVar` variable to ant directly by using `ant -DtestVar=John -buildfile build.xml hello` command.

How can I do the same thing using gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that changing *build.gradle* file to

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
ant.properties['testVar'] = testVar
```

solves the problem.

After the modification, `gradle -PtestVar=Ken hello` generates

```
> Task :hello
[ant:echo] Hello, I'm Ken
```

which is the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

`-P` is used for passing properties directly to your Gradle build. Your Gradle script will see these properties but your Ant script won't. The answer you provided technically works, but could become tedious as you'll have to make sure you're passing every property from Gradle to Ant in your Gradle script.

If you want to provide a property to Ant, use `-D` instead.